# Redirect request to http and https both

Tags: laravel, apache, http, https

Hy,

I want to redirect http request to https only when ssl is not expired and if ssl expired then keep request in http.

How can I do this?

I have api in my laravel project.

Need anymore information let me know.

Comment: What do you mean with "https only when ssl is not expired", do you mean meanwhile the SSL certificate is valid?

Comment: Sounds like a classic [x-y-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/364505): Get your key management in order - typically you have 3 months to 2 years validity of a certificate. Within that time either automate renewal or set a calendar reminder. Future browsers might assume https anyway, so you'd have a lot of work for only a few edge cases when people explicitly enter http in the URL or follow old links.

Comment: @matiaslauriti yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Add below code in your .htaccess file after rewrite engine on

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}  != on 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cron job to auto renew the certification (in case of Let's encrypt )

Forget to use complex rule to verify the validaty of SSL certification

they are a lot of article , about configure redirection from Http tp Https

https://linuxize.com/post/redirect-http-to-https-in-apache/

https://www.tecmint.com/redirect-http-to-https-on-apache/